# CORS issue while getting access token using client_credentials using javascript/reactjs from microsoft graph /token?

Tags: javascript, oauth, cors, fetch, microsoft-graph-api

I need to get the access token using fetch() method but i am unable to do so with the fetch() method. Tried allowinng Cors-policy or cross-Access-Origin to all but nothing seems to working.

**Access to fetch at 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/common/oauth2/v2.0/token' from origin 'http://localhost:3050' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.**

**graphService.ts:81 POST https://login.microsoftonline.com//common/oauth2/v2.0/token net::ERR_FAILED**

Thanks in Advance:)

Answer (score 2):

You are getting cors error because Azure AD rejects the request when you include **Origin** header while using **client_credentials**. To start with You are using the **client_credentials** flow the wrong way.
Consider reading through this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) on client credentials flow to help you understand why its preferred for server side / daemon applications.

To see the error just add Origin header to postman and do the request again.

Also read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols) to understand the oauth2 flows that you can use

For your case, you can use [authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) because you have an SPA.

Answer (score -1):

It is not the flow or configuration that is causing the issue. The real issue is front-end or SPA. IF you want to call the API for getting token with client Credential flow,You must follow either of the two approaches that is a mandatory thing I guess.

**1.Daemon Services**

**2.Server side Implementation**

I have called the API with Node and with same configuration as mention in the docs its working fine now.
msal-node npm package is an alternate to call the api or you can call the graph api by yourself.

```js
async getAppTokenFromAzureAD() : Promise <any | Error> {
        const requestHeaders : HeadersInit = new Headers();
        var details = {
            'client_secret' : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            'client_id':'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            'scope':'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default',
            'grant_type':"client_credentials"
        };
        
        let formBody:any = [];
        for (var property in details) {
          var encodedKey = encodeURIComponent(property);
          var encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(details[property]);
          formBody.push(encodedKey + "=" + encodedValue);
        }
        formBody = formBody.join("&");
        requestHeaders.set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        requestHeaders.set('Host','login.microsoftonline.com');
        return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
            this.connection.transaction(async (entityManager) => {
                try {
                    let tokenResponse = fetch('https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx9/oauth2/v2.0/token',{
                        method : 'POST',
                        headers : requestHeaders,
                        body : formBody

                    })
                    tokenResponse.then(data=>data.json()).then(responses=>{
                        resolve({
                            statusMessage: getMessageByKey('apllicationTokenSuccess'),
                            responses,
                        })
                    }).catch(error=>{
                        reject(error);
                    })
                } catch (error) {
                    reject(error)
                }
            })
        })
    }
```

Thanks